# first-class module in Coq

Tags: coq

Could anyone give me more information about the first-class module in Coq? I know that module in Coq is not a first-class. I would like to know the reason why? and is it possible that in the future module in Coq can be first-class?

Thank you very much

Comment: random guess: the usefulness of first class modules in code reuse doesn't outweigh the complexity of (reasoning about) them for most people.  (Only recently did OCaml get first class modules.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not certain, but as I understand it it comes from essentially two points:

1. **Coq is conservative.** Because some of its main applications are in verification, Coq mostly restricts itself to constructs whose semantics are reasonably well-understood.
2. **In the dependent-types setting, first-class modules are rather subtle and not fully understood.**  In particular, how much of the computational/reduction behaviour of definitions do you want visible outside a module?  If none at all, then this is already available, as record types.  But if some or all of the reduction behaviour is visible, then it’s hard to quantify exactly how much is, so it’s quite hard to analyse the semantics of the resulting modules.

I’m not an expert on the relevant literature, so I may well be wrong about 2, but I’ve gotten the impression that this is the basic situation.